# How can i click my html (DOM) and open an existing popup on my Leaflet Map. Im only using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, leaflet, dom-events

Im trying to conect my "See in map" (html) with my map and open a popUp that is already created (i click on the map and the popups open).

i know i have to use something like

```
L.DomEvent.on(tiendas,'click',function(e){
   console.log('Button clicked')
});
```

but i dont know how to do it. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that all of your links have the same `id="tiendanombre"` attribute - is this intentional (id attributes should be unique on the page)?

According to this answer [How to open leaflet marker popup from link outside of map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632359/how-to-open-leaflet-marker-popup-from-link-outside-of-map) the marker has an `openPopup()` method that we need to call

In your HTML template is there a way that we can identify which entry in your `diet` array the link refers to? Is the HTML generated from the same array maybe?

If we can get an identifier into the HTML, for example

```
<a href="#" class="icon-link" data-diet-id="{Identifier that also appears in diet array}">Open in map</a>
```

Then we can look for that link when we are in your `forEach` loop, after you have made your marker

```
const marker = new L.marker(diet[i][0], diet[i][1]).bindPopup(etc etc);

// We need to find the link that corresponds to this marker.
// if the HTML was generated from the same diet array this will be quite simple,
// because it will be in the same position in the list of '.tiendaNombre a.icon-link' elements

// const link = document.querySelectorAll('.tiendaNombre a.icon-link')[i]

// otherwise if we have added an identifier to our HTML then we will need to find our link using that
const selector = `a[data-diet-id="${diet[i][IndexOfTheIdentifierField]}"]`;
const link = document.querySelector(selector);

// once we have found our link we just need to tell it what to do when it gets clicked
if(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   marker.openPopup(); 
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Yes, i made a big mistake there where i wrote Id (rookie mistake) thanks for that. 
I will try your code and let you know, im new in this javascript world so every line of code is always new for me. Thanks again, have a nice day!